# How do you get a rowcount into SQL insert statements generated in Excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, excel

I'm generating SQL insert statements in Excel, but I've encountered a problem. The primary key of the table these statements apply to is not an auto-incrementing identity. I'm trying to find a way I can get a rowcount in Excel into the insert statements it's generating (thus effectively giving my rows an identity; or at least getting SQL Server to stop complaining upon execution).

Does anyone out there know of anything already built into Excel that will allow me to pull this off? If not, does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an `IDENTITY` specified on the column?

Comment: If not `IDENTITY`, what is it? I mean, it would appear to be a unique integer but are there any other constraints? Could you, for example, pick a value far from zero (positive or negative) which would have a very low chance of generating clashes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select from the table to get the max of the primary key
2. Set the value to a variable, such as `rowCount`
3. As you loop the Excel spreadsheet, increment the count by 1 and use that value for the insert statement

**EDIT**: Added example

```
DECLARE @MaxCount INT
SELECT @MaxCount = MAX(ID) FROM SomeTable

INSERT INTO (ID, ...) VALUES (@MaxCount + 1, ...)
```

Comment: I'm confused (perhaps misunderstanding your answer) -- are all three of those steps supposed to be done within SQL Management Studio? Also, SQL Server complains if you try doing a select inside a values clause, so unless there's a way to assign/increment inside a values clause, I'm not sure what you're getting at here..

Comment: @KSwift87: You wouldn't be doing a select inside the values clause; you would be putting the max id into a variable before the insert, and using the variable in the values clause.